# Rewrite URL containing a period symbol with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello im trying to rewrite my url `www.example.com/user.php?user=user.name` as `www.example.com/user.name`

but im getting an error message, I think the dot is messing things up.. here is my rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to set `RewriteCond` first

Answer (score 4):

Use this RewriteRule:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# forward to user.php in a Query parameter user
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If you don't use these RewriteCond lines then even files like `style.css`, `site.js`, `favicon.ico` will also be forwarded to `user.php` and won't render in the browser.

Comment: @anubhava **Awesome**, dude. Thanks. The rules you have given is really quite useful to understand how htaccess works properly. Life & time saver answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern instead: `^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]+)$`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

(Just added the dot and escaped the dash in the list of possible characters)

Also, don't forget to put a `RewriteCond` beforehand to avoid infinite loops. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^user\.php$
```

Note that this supposes you don't have a user whose name is user.php ;)